# Accessing HttpRUntime.Cache in console app

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, httpruntime.cache

I have a console app that needs to dynamically load all the endpoints in my API app and get the details of the data that is cached.

```
    foreach (var routeTemplate in listRouteTempplates)
    {
                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/appName/" + routeTemplate );
                    WebResponse response = null;
                    Stream dataStream = null;
                    request.Method = HttpMethod.Get.ToString();

                    response = request.GetResponse();
                    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                    responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    reader.Close();
                    dataStream.Close();
                    response.Close();

                    var count=HttpRuntime.Cache.Count;
    }
```

When invoking each endpoint, the data retrieved is also cached. I confirmed that by calling the endpoints directly (via postman) and checking the cache.

But in the console app, even though the response does have the correct data, the count of items in HttpRuntime.Cache is always zero.

Is there a reason the data is not cached when I call the endpoints in a console app ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cache in which items are stored lives on the server inside your Web API host. It is then normal that the cache instance that you are checking inside your client console application doesn't have any items in it - those are 2 completely different object instances living in 2 different applications.

Comment: I have seen unit tests access the HttpRuntime.Cache - which is why I assumed that invoking the endpoints would add the data to the cache. If both are two different instances, then how could you do unit tests for classes that utilize cache ?

Comment: You would do unit test of your Web API controller, not using a console application or an HTTP client. Like this: `var controller = new MyApiController(); var actual = controller.Get(); // assert here that after calling the Get method on the Web API controller the data is being cached`.

Comment: That makes sense, Marking as answer. Thanks for the help.